# Moq class with constructors ILogger and options netcore 2.1 vs2017 getting error

Tags: asp.net-core, moq

I need to mock a class that has parameters in the constructor by I cannot figure out how you do it using moq. It crashes

> Constructor arguments cannot be passed for interface mocks.

See my attempt below:

```
   [Fact]
    public async Task MyTest()
    {
        var mySettings= GetMySettings();
        var mySettingsOptions = Options.Create(mySettings);
        var mockLogger = Mock.Of<ILogger<MyClass>>();


        var mock=new Mock<IMyClass>(mySettings,mockLogger);
        mock.Setup(x=>x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>().Returns("todo");
    }


    public class MyClass : IMyClass
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyClass> logger;
        private readonly MySettings mySettings;

        public MyClass(IOptions<MySettings> settings,ILogger<MyClass>logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
            this.mySettings = settings.Value;
        }


        public string DoSomething(string myarg)
        {                                
          //omitted
        }

    }
```

How do you do it? many thanks

**EDITED**

In order to mock repository and test the behaviour i also need to mock the other classes that have constructors in it. Hope makes sense

```
public class MyService:IMyService
{
    private MyClass myclass;
    private OtherClass otherClass;
    private Repository repository;


    public MyService(IRepository repository,IMyClass myclass,IMyOtherClass otherClass)
    {
        this.myclass=myClass;
        this.otherClass=otherClass;
        this.repository=repository;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        bool valid1=myclass.Validate();   //mock myclass
        var valid2=otherClass.Validate(); //mock otherClass


        if(Valid1 && valid2)
        {
            repository.GetSomething();//this is really what I am mocking
        }
        //etc..

    }
}
```

Comment: What is actually your goal? Do you want to test DoSomething method? Or want to mock IMyClass to pass it to another class?

Comment: @AlexRiabov i have edited my question

Comment: so you shouldn't care about constuctors for objects you're mocking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter if your class constructor has parameters or not, because you're working with its mock object.

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();
mock.Setup(x=>x.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns("todo");
```

Then you can use this mock to your repository constructor:

```
var myService = new MyService(repositoryMock.Object, mock.Object, otherClassMock.Object);
```

Comment: you are right I was overcomplicating things for no reasons.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are trying to create a mock of an interface (`IMyClass` in this case) with constructor values. It seems like you are trying to test the method in the class `MyClass`, therefore you should be creating a moq of this class. 
To clarify change 
`var mock=new Mock<IMyClass>(mySettings,mockLogger);` to `var mock=new Mock<MyClass>(mySettings,mockLogger);`